# Django changes datetime automatically

Tags: postgresql

I have django project and one separate service.

In django timezone is UTC+3 and in separate service I have written pure sql codes

like below

```
INSERT INTO  Table(something,something,datetime) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)
```

as a datetime field if I send **2021-04-28 01:00:00**, django will save it **2021-04-28 04:00:00**,

3 hours more. How can I implement db to store exactly what I send there.

Comment: If you are executing raw SQL then Django has nothing to do with this behaviour.  Instead, review the Postgresql docs for datetime/timestamp fields.

Comment: Have you tried to insert a timestamp with timezone information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date and time in UTC - how to store them in postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432682/date-and-time-in-utc-how-to-store-them-in-postgres)